# VirtualStringTree how to disable alpha blended selection while doing drag and drop?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, alphablending, virtualtreeview

When drag and dropping items from one `TVirtualStringTree` to another `TVirtualStringTree` how do I **disable** semi-transparent selection block shown while dragging the selection over the destination tree?

I've tried all the options and still cannot find the right one.

[image]

Comment: Set the `DragType` property of the source VST to `dtVCL` (default is `dtOLE`)

Comment: Thank you, I also figured now that `DragWidth` can be set to 0 (default is 200) which has the same effect without modifying `DragType`. If you want to make it into an answer I will gladly approve it, otherwise I'll make an answer in a day or two myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can omit the image by changing `DragType` from default `dtOLE` to `dtVCL`. Additionally `DragWidth` can be set to 0 which will have the same effect.